# how to pull posts from wordpress to other non-wordpress site on different hosting?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp-2.0

How can I pull the posts of one blogger(written on his wordpress blog) to my site without installing the wordpress on my site? What are requirements and limitations of doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple ways to use wordpress as a CMS only, without actually using it as your site or to expose content for use on another site.

RSS feeds as noted in another answer is good for read-only access to posts.  To interact with content you'll need another solution.

You can enable XML-RPC in wordpress and use a library like php xmlrpc to connect and pull post data.  However, XML-RPC is limited out of the box and mostly geared towards publishing to wordpress, not pulling out stuff.

The most flexible solutions is a REST plugin for wordpress that expose your posts via restful API.  Check out:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

One limitation is you'll obvioiusly not have some of the wordpress-as-a-website-building-tool plugin  functionality available on the non-wordpress site.

Comment: Thanks Ray! Let me explain you what my problem is, so that you can help me out. I am working on a site www.gymup.com. There are some trainer on this site. Suppose one of trainer wants to pull his post from wordpress and want to put in article section of site. So,Is there any way I can implement this functionality.

Comment: @AvMishra the json api pluging should work.  Once enabled, In your code you connect to it via curl or http_request2 library (if you're using php).  You can pull posts by slug or anything else.  They come back as a json object which you can decode and use in your code.

Comment: @AvMishra Once you install the plugin, you can hit it with simple get requests to see if you've got everything you need.  See this link for api resource urls: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

Comment: Thanks Ray! you mean to say I have to install plugin in my non-wordpress site i.e. www.gymup.com. So I how would I configure the wp_config file? I don't have any database for wordpress and how I my different trainers can use this plugin to pull his blog on my site? Please suggest me.

Comment: @AvMishra. The plugin goes on the wordpress site and that site then exposes all posts with a REST api.  You will need to be familiar with how to connect to a rest webservice with your code.

Comment: Thanks Ray! got your point, it means my trainer would have to install plugin in his wordpress site if they don't my site cannot pull their post. am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If it's WordPress you could just use the RSS Feed to syndicate content to your site?

To grab the content you want - http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Comment: thanks Alex! but as I know "/feed" pulls only brief description of post not whole content. I am looking for to grab full post description. Thanks again.

Comment: That depends on the bloggers WordPress settings - under "Settings > Reading" there is an option `For each article in a feed, show` with radio buttons for "Full Text" and "Summary", where "Summary" gives you the description/excerpt

Comment: thanks Alex! I have a testing blog of mine but even on selecting the Full Text, feed showing me "Continue reading →". Still not giving whole content. you can see my testing blog on here http://avmishra.wordpress.com/feed/ . Am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure - http://nnbox.ca/2010/03/hack-fix-for-wordpress-2-9-not-displaying-full-text-rss/ might shed some light?

Comment: NP. Thanks allot Alex! for your valuable help. by the way opera is showing full text but FF not =).

Comment: I did hear it was a browser issue at some level - hopefully it's simple to resolve! Glad to help =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the plugin Wp RSS Multi importer should do the trick. It pulls out RSS feeds from the blog you want to syndicate into your own blog. You can get the plugin here http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-multi-importer/. The problem could be if what you want is not a feed. I for example want content that looks like this http://bake.co.ke/pg/recent+blog+posts. I don't want to syndicate feeds but the real content from another website.