# How to get post thumbnails outside Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to get post title, date and content (or excerpt) of the post thumbnail all together while getting the url and image src separately. I'm working around this query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Using the query above, how to get also the posts thumbnail? I'm retrieving all data by this way:

```
<?php
        #start a loop that starts $i at 0, and make increase until it's at the number of rows
        for($i=0; $i< $num_rows; $i++) {

        #assign data to variables, $i is the row number, which increases with each run of the loop
        $blog_date = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_date");
        $blog_title = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_title");
        $blog_excerpt = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_excerpt");
        $blog_content = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_content");

        #$blog_permalink = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "guid"); //use this line for p=11 format.
        $blog_permalink = $blog_url . mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_name"); //combine blog url, with permalink title. Use this for title format

        #format date
        $blog_date = strtotime($blog_date);
        $blog_date = strftime("%b %e", $blog_date);
        ?>

        <div class="post">
            <div class="date"><?php echo $blog_date; ?></div>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $blog_permalink; ?>"><?php echo $blog_title; ?></a></h2>
            <div class="entry">
                <?php echo $blog_excerpt; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php } #ends loop ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) outside of `WordPress` just like

```
<?php
require( 'your_wordpress_root_folder/wp-load.php' );
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
<?php the_post_thumbnail() ?></a>
<?php
    endif;
endwhile;
```

Comment: The problem is: I need to get posts from an installation on another domain, totally outside location where I need to retrieve the posts.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589025/how-to-pull-posts-from-wordpress-to-other-non-wordpress-site-on-different-hostin).